# yacc - field has incomplete type

Tags: c, bison, yacc

yacc doesn't seem to like when my tokens are of a type that I defined.

At the top of my grammar (`.y`) file in a `%{ ... %}` block, I include a header file that defines the following structure:

```
typedef struct _spim_register {
    spim_register_type type; /* This is a simple enumeration, already defined */
    int number;              
} spim_register;
```

Before my list of rules, I have:

```
%token AREG
...
%union {
struct _spim_register reg;
}
...
%type <reg> register AREG
```

I get

> error: field ‘reg’ has incomplete type

at the line in the `%union` clause while trying to compile the code produced by bison. In my `%union` statement, trying to declare reg by writing `spim_register reg;` gives the error:

```
unknown type name ‘spim_register’
```

It seems like there's something special about `%union { ... }`, because I'm able to use the data structures from my header file in the actions for the rules.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430390/include-struct-in-the-union-def-with-bison-yacc)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would help if my `#includes` were in the right order...

The answer was, as user786653 hinted, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430390/include-struct-in-the-union-def-with-bison-yacc). I needed to include the header file that defines my custom structure **before** including the `.tab.h` file in the `.l` file.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I met the same problem. Because my `*.l` file was like this:

```c
#include "y.tab.h"
#include "FP.h"
```

I rewrote it like this:

```c
#include "FP.h"
#include "y.tab.h"
```

It works.

Comment: Working in xcode I found I needed to delete the Derived Data for my project in order for the reordering to actually happen.  For some reason, xcode was not actually including the new file.