# Freeing pointers in `struct` used as model for `%union`

Tags: c, bison

There are a couple nice questions addressing use of structs in the Bison `%union` (notably [Include struct in the %union def with Bison/Yacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430390/)), but I think they fail to specify that, if a `struct` with pointers is defined, and then those pointers are used (so I have to allocate some memory for them), who's responsibility is to `free(void *)` them.

**Am I responsible for freeing pointers in this situation?**

**If a memory error occurs then how do I debug it?**

Comment: Can't you traverse the parsed tree and free the resources once you are done with the tree (or a sub tree)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [freeing the string allocated in strdup() from flex/bison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104302/freeing-the-string-allocated-in-strdup-from-flex-bison).

Comment: I've no idea @AjayBrahmakshatriya. I guess now that's something I shall research.

Comment: @melpomene thank you, by what I read in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105408/1737973, I think serializing the object in a string should also be viable as a solution for issues I'm surely going to hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to free the pointers when you're done with them.  That means that in an action that runs for a reduce with those pointers, you need to do it in that action (unless you copy the pointers elsewhere that will 'own' them).

The tricky part is dealing with error recovery -- after a syntax error, bison will pop and discard items in an attempt to recover.  Fortunately, bison provides the `%destructor` directive which can be used to clean up, freeing these pointers as they are discarded.

Comment: I'm surely stepping in some kind of anti pattern here, but I just don't want to free the reserved memory in the production rule. I want to create a custom variant like struct, and let the next production rule manipulate it. Which makes that upper production rule a good candidate to be the point which frees the child's struct and every hanging resource. I wonder if Bison would support that, but I can try that easily.

Comment: Aha, understood. I guess copying the pointers elsewhere owning them will do. I just want each node tree holding an UUID to identify it. That looks like an awesome way to do what I want, and also looks like a nice easener for a potential migration to a custom parser in replacement for Bison, or to a different LALR parser generator provider (for whatever reason).

Comment: For the sake of the single responsibility principle, the code as a whole should look nicer and more maintainable if I limit the Bison use here to it's thing - parsing - as much as possible, proxying variant manipulation elsewhere.

Comment: `after a syntax error, bison will pop and discard items in an attempt to recover` Does this mean nodes ought to be immutable? Can avoiding _shift or reduce_ conflicts help get less syntax errors?

Comment: @uprego: Not sure quite what you're asking here, but conflicts have nothing to do with syntax errors.