# Yacc Error: Field has Incomplete Type for Declared Structures

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, yacc

I am working on building a parser using Yacc and Lex, and I have defined several structures in a shared header file (shared_vars.h). I have initialized these structures in a C file (shared_vars.c) within the main function. However, when I try to use these structures in the Yacc file (ex.yacc), I encounter errors related to incomplete types.

The structures are defined as follows in shared_vars.h:

```
struct CtlInfo {
    // fields
};

struct Ctl_LobFile_spec {
    // fields
};

struct Ctl_pos_spec {
    // fields
};

struct Ctl_Scalar_spec {
    // fields
};

struct Ctl_filed_list {
    // fields
};
```

In the Yacc file (ex.yacc), I have included the necessary header files and added the structures to the %union declaration:

```
%union {
    int ival;
    float fval;
    char* sval;
    struct CtlInfo ctlinfo;           // Forward declaration in header file
    struct Ctl_LobFile_spec lobfile_spec; // Forward declaration in header file
    struct Ctl_pos_spec pos_spec;     // Forward declaration in header file
    struct Ctl_Scalar_spec scalar_spec; // Forward declaration in header file
    struct Ctl_filed_list *field_list; // Note: This is a pointer to struct Ctl_filed_list
}
%type <pos_spec>
```

However, during compilation, I receive the following errors:

```
ex.yacc:229:29: error: field has incomplete type 'struct Ctl_LobFile_spec'
    struct Ctl_LobFile_spec lobfile_spec;
                            ^
ex.yacc:229:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct Ctl_LobFile_spec'
    struct Ctl_LobFile_spec lobfile_spec;
           ^
ex.yacc:230:25: error: field has incomplete type 'struct Ctl_pos_spec'
    struct Ctl_pos_spec pos_spec;
                        ^
ex.yacc:230:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct Ctl_pos_spec'
    struct Ctl_pos_spec pos_spec;
           ^
ex.yacc:231:28: error: field has incomplete type 'struct Ctl_Scalar_spec'
    struct Ctl_Scalar_spec scalar_spec;
                           ^
ex.yacc:231:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct Ctl_Scalar_spec'
    struct Ctl_Scalar_spec scalar_spec;
           ^
3 errors generated.
```

Comment: You can't use forward references in a union declaration. It needs to know the size of each member.

Comment: it mention as a forward declariton though they are extern structs

Comment: so I have to copy all the things in my .h file  to the union so it will be able to resolve it ?

Comment: `extern` refers to variables, not types.

Comment: No, just include the header file that declares the structs before the union.

Comment: can i use these extern as types, I belive they are not in the union it will fire an error

Comment: I did indeed, included the header file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254785/discussion-between-amrshams07-and-barmar).

Comment: Do you literally have `struct CtlInfo {`
`// fields` `};` in the header file? That is not a proper declaration. You should declare the members.

Comment: Just a guess ... Did you put the `#include` inside a block? That is: `%{\n#include <mystruct.h>\n%}\n` at the top (this comes from `info bison`)

Comment: yes absolutely, I made sure it is in the code section

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430390/include-struct-in-the-union-def-with-bison-yacc) might be helpful

use the %code directive with the "requires"

```
%code requires {
    struct CtlInfo {
    // fields
    };
}
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue arose from how I handled memory inside the rules, specifically the return type of each rule. Since the rules returned dynamically allocated pointers, I modified the structs to be pointers rather than local structs.